# Iterate over columns, find selection, create new column

Tags: python, string, pandas, for-loop

I am trying to webscraep of a website and create a dataframe of name and image link.
But there are some issues while I parse the name.

My dataframe looks like this;

```
color    gender    model1    model2  extra_col1  extra_col2    extra_col3
black    male       A24      B2       
red      woman      A1       B3
19sf     black      male     A22        B1
deep     1909sf     2202     blue       woman         A1          B22
```

First two rows is correct. I want to iterate over these 7 columns and find color, gender and model correctly and create new columns;

In the end below table is what I want;

```
color    gender    model1    model2     
black    male       A24      B2                                           
red      woman      A1       B3
black    male       A22      B1
blue     woman      A1       B22
```

I have the lists of unique values of color,gender,model1,model2
I need to compare each element in that specific columns and match with lists and write correct one in color column, gender column, etc.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add a snippet of how your data looks before putting it in a dataframe?

Comment: Looks to me (as per your sample) that you want to always end up with the last 4 columns? Am I right?

Comment: You are trying to fix the data after feeding the dataframe, when it would be better to fix the way you feed the dataframe. It is indeed possible to fix the dataframe itself but you will have to use the worse possible pandas technics while fixing the original data is certainly much nicer.

Comment: @jvdV yes you're right.

Comment: @Serge Ballesta it is a html object so in general there should be 4 elements like in the last table in post. I guess it is better to do that operation once and for all, otherwise while I scraping I need to check every element in for loop which I don't prefer

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's definately not clean. A `Python` pro would definately have their concerns, but as I'm new to `Python` and `Pandas` I just gave it a shot using some `Join`, `Regular Expressions` and `Split`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'color':['black','red','19sf','deep'],
                   'gender':['male','woman','black','1909sf'],
                   'model1':['A24','A1','Male','2202'],
                   'model2':['B2','B3','A22','blue'],
                   'extra_col1':['','','B1','woman'],
                   'extra_col2':['','','','A1'],
                   'extra_col3':['','','','B22']})
df = df[df.columns[0:]].apply(lambda x: '|'.join(x.dropna().astype(str)), axis=1)
df = df.replace(r'.*?((?:\w+\|){3}\w+(?=\|*$)).*', value = r'\1', regex = True)
df = df.str.split('|', expand = True)
df.columns = ['color','gender','model1','model2']
print(df)
```

So again, while I'm very new to programming outside `VBA` this does the job, but can probably be done much neater. Fingers crossed it works for you =)

Comment: Any luck?? @Tyr

Comment: thanks for your answer! It is working for given dataset but I need more generalized solution like matching color list in columns. For example "black" should be searched in all columns and write to color column for given row.

Comment: That's why I asked beforehand if you would always need to get the last 4 non-empty values, which you said was right. @Tyr. I'd be out of ideas now =). Good luck.

Comment: I understand "last 4 columns" as last table in question. Thanks anyway:)

Comment: @Tyr, unless you tackle this issue with the source data, I think if would be hard to know for any programming language to know exactly where to search what value and where to put it. What if no valid value was to be found in first column, how would you expect code to understand to search for black or any other color and put it in column 1? Would be interesting to see if anyone can come up with something more generalised.

Comment: @Tyr, have you had any luck? Would be interesting to see what you came up with